How to Efficiently Compute the Meet of Two Trees with "Holes"?
While working on a compiler I stumbled with the problem of trying to efficiently merge two trees that contain "holes." These trees represent types, where the leaves are simple types (e.g., int, bool), and the inner nodes are either structural types (e.g., ty -> ty, ty * ty) or "holes," denoted by ?.
The operation I'm interested in is computing the "meet" of two such trees, which is defined as follows:

meet(ty, ?) = ty
meet(?, ty) = ty
meet(Int, Int) = Int
meet(Bool, Bool) = Bool
if meet(ty1, ty1') = ty1'' and meet(ty2, ty2') = ty2'', then meet(ty1 -> ty2, ty1' -> ty2') = ty1''-> ty2''
if meet(ty1, ty1') = ty1'' and meet(ty2, ty2') = ty2'', then meet(ty1 * ty2, ty1' * ty2') = ty1'' * ty2''
otherwise, meet is not defined and the function should raise an error

My current implementation involves using three pointers, one for each argument and one for the result. Both trees are traversed simultaneously using a DFS traversal, while copying the matching nodes to the result tree. When a hole is encountered I copy the entire subtree to the result.
I implemented the tree in C using a tagged union. Simple types are stored directly and complex types are pointers to a flat block of memory.

It looks like you want type unification.

I'm aware of type unification, but this problem is a different and much simpler.

Yes your problem as stated is simpler, the question is whether it is enough, or will need type unification anyway at some point. Your current algorithm seems to be as efficient as it gets. To make it more efficient, you can represent your trees with shared pointers (but then you have to implement reference counting or some other garbage collection scheme yourself) or unique pointers (and destroy your arguments while computing the result).

I get your comment now. I don't need type unification since the compiler I'm working on doesn't do type inference. However, the language being compiled is a gradually typed language, so there are runtime checks that involve the meet operation.
I will eventually add garbage collection, so I don't need to worry about reference counting for now.

There's another way of doing this. If your types are represented as strings, you can just scan two strings in parallel and copy any characters that are equal. Otherwise if you meet a ? on one side, copy a type from the other side by counting parentheses. (You may want to include every type in a pair of parentheses). Otherwise there is an error.
